# How to subset columns in the same line as a .loc in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Efficiency question here. Sometimes I want to run a `.loc` and look at certain columns after doing so. The way I've always done it is the following

```
p = df[(df.x==1)]
p(['x','y'])
```

This would return cells with a value of `1` from column `x` then subset the dataframe to look at just columns `x` and `y`. Is there a way I can do this in one line without the variable assignment? Things I have tried include

```
df[(df.x==1)].columns(['x','y'])
```

```
df[(df.x==1),['x','y'])
```

I do this a lot and would love if I could make it one line of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don’t chain your index. Instead l, use `loc`

```
df.loc[df.x==1, ['x','y']]
```

The general syntax is

```
df.loc[index_slice, column_slice]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter for spesific columns of a dataframe by slicing it with a list of column names, like `df[['col1', 'col']]`. So in your example, you can do that to the filtered dataframe:

```
df[df.x==1][['x', 'y']]
```